# Variavel com href

Tags: php, variáveis

Preciso que a variavel celular `Celular: $lnbusca[celular]` de para clicar e apareça na tela de discagem exemploo `<a href="tel:55555"> chamar 5555</a>` para a hora que o usuario ao clicar apareça o numero na tela de discagem do celular, então como faço para colocar o `href`dentro do $`lnbusca[]`, como faço ?

```html
<?php
include "config.php";
if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'bsc'){
 $palavra = strip_tags($_POST['pesquisa']);
 
 $banco = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE nome LIKE '%$palavra%'");
 
 if(mysql_num_rows($banco) == 0){
  echo "Nenhum dado foi encontrado!";
 }else{
  while($lnbusca = mysql_fetch_array($banco)){
                            
                            //COMECO
                            
                            
                            echo "<table width=1000 align=center>";

echo "<td bgcolor=#ebf3ff><b></b>";
echo "</td>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width=25>";

echo "<font size=1>Codigo: $lnbusca[id_contato]</font>";

echo "</td>";


    echo "<td width=450 bgcolor=#ebf3ff>";
 
    
//echo "<b><a href='agenda-exibir.php?id_contato={$dados['codigo']}'><font color=black size=elvetica>$dados[nome]</font></a><br />";
echo "<b><font color=black size=elvetica>Categoria: $lnbusca[categoria] | "
            . "Cidade: $lnbusca[cidade] | "
            . "Nome: $lnbusca[nome] | "
            . "Celular: $lnbusca[celular] | "
            . "Celular2: $lnbusca[celular2] | "
            . "Telefone: $lnbusca[telefone]  </font></a><br />";

echo "</tr>";
echo "</td>";
   

echo "<td bgcolor=#f8f8fA>";
echo "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
    echo "</td>";

echo "</table>";                                //FIMM
  }
}}
    
  
?>
```

Comment: Tente ser mais claro na pergunta, colocar algum trecho de código que você já fez. Fica difícil ajudar sem os detalhes

Comment: da pra fazer assim `<a href="tel:<?php echo $lnbusca['celular']; ?>"> Chamar <?php echo $lnbusca['celular']; ?> </a>`

Comment: Postei o codigo deem uma olhada o problema esta aqui em adiconar o href . "Celular2: $lnbusca[celular2] | " da uma olhada daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, temos que arrumar os erros de sintaxe.

Arrays permitem índices numéricos ou string. No seu caso você não especificou nem uma coisa nem outra.

```
$lnbusca[celular]   // celular não é uma string, tampouco número
$lnbusca['celular'] // Assim está correto como string
$lnbusca[$celular]  // Assim está correto se o índice vier de uma variável
```

Outro problema é a interpolação de *String*. O PHP permite que você coloque variáveis dentro de uma string, se usar aspas duplas. Entretanto, se precisar especificar algo mais complexo, precisa delimitar com `{ }`.

No seu caso, aplicando as duas coisas mencionadas, o código "correto" seria este:

```
echo "<b><font color=black size=elvetica>Categoria: {$lnbusca['categoria']} | "
    ."Cidade: {$lnbusca['cidade']} | "
    ."Nome: {$lnbusca['nome']} | "
    ."Celular: {$lnbusca['celular']} | "
    ."Celular2: {$lnbusca['celular2']} | "
    ."Telefone: {$lnbusca['telefone']}  </font></a><br />";
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/H68dPm)**.

### Adicionando o `href`

Entendido o passo anterior, basta acrescentar o que quiser nas *strings*.

Em vez de

```
"Celular: {$lnbusca['celular']} | "
```

poderia se fazer isso (note a barra invertida para as aspas do `href`):

```
"Celular: <a href=\"tel:{$lnbusca['celular']}\"> Chamar {$lnbusca['celular']}</a> | "
```

Ou isso, para evitar interpolação e confusão com aspas:

```
'Celular: <a href="tel:'.$lnbusca['celular'].'"> Chamar '.$lnbusca['celular'].'</a> | '
```

### Removendo a interpolação

A interpolação é cômoda para se colocar pequenos detalhes e variáveis numa *string*, facilitando a legibilidade quando se quer evitar a concatenação. No seu caso não ajuda muito, pois está havendo concatenação de qualquer forma. Assim, seria possível simplificar o código usando concatenação em tudo:

```
echo '<b><font color=black size=elvetica>'
    .   'Categoria: '.$lnbusca['categoria']
    .' | Cidade: '   .$lnbusca['cidade']
    .' | Nome: '     .$lnbusca['nome']
    .' | Celular: '  .$lnbusca['celular']
    .' | Celular2: ' .$lnbusca['celular2']
    .' | Telefone: ' .$lnbusca['telefone']
    .' </font></a><br />';
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/wcha3y)**.

<sup><sub>Não entrei no mérito do seu HTML estar um bocado estranho, porque foge da pergunta, mas sugiro revisar de qualquer forma</sub></sup>

Comment: Mestre fico perfeita sua resposta muito agradecido por ter respondido grande abraço para você muito obrigado..